# Richfaces 4.2 and TinyMCE

Tags: jsf, richfaces, tinymce-3

I am trying to use Richfaces 4.2 and my own custom TinyMCE rich text editor (based on version 3.5.11).

The editor was installed like the official tutorial (http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Installation). It works and the editor is applied to any textarea.

My problem is after ajax submits, when the form is re-rendered, so the TinyMCE instance is lost and not applied anymore.

Is there some way to deal with it, reapplying the TinyMCE on every ajax submit or any other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround that allowed TinyMCE to interact with Richfaces ajax actions and renders, so I will answer my own question although I believe its not the best answer possible.

Here is my solution:

Copy TinyMCE folder to my WebContent/js folder, including the tiny.js which is a init file (external file optional).

This file contains both the tinyMCE init config and the JSF2 javascript that join tinyMCE and render actions.

Here is the tiny.js code:

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
switch(data.status) {
    case "begin":
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        break;

    case "complete":
        break;

    case "success":
        var i, t = tinyMCE.editors;
        for (i in t){
            if (t.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                t[i].remove();
            }
        }

        tinyMCEinit();
        break;
}});

function tinyMCEinit(){  
tinyMCE.init({
    language : "pt",
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    mode : "textareas" 
});}
```

What JSF 2 Javascript do is call the tinyMCEinit() function that cleans all textareas and reapply it all again. It works nice when you open the page for the first time, maybe a little heavy DOM processing, but the final user will no notice the loading... unless you page have 4 texareas/editors and need to be editable like a list of Alternatives Question. 4 editors on the same page have slow loading time and previous rich:editor/ckeditor will notice the performance lost.

Well, one little touch of javascript needs to be added to your "Save" buttons like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton onclick="tinyMCE.triggerSave();" render="some_panel" value="Any render"></a4j:commandButton>
```

The triggerSave() transfer the values (html) on the editor to the h:inputTextarea so JSF can grab the values and send it to the backend.